# Show the inverse of a bijective linear operator is continuous iff $\inf_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\|>0$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $T : X → Y$ be a bijective linear operator between normed spaces $X$, $Y$. Show that
the inverse $T^{-1}$ is continuous if and only if
$\inf_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\|>0$

I have the solution as 
Let $α =\inf_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\|>0$

Then for $x \neq 0$,

$\|T(x)\| = \|x\|\|T(\frac{x}{\|x\|})\| \geq \alpha \|x\|$

Hence  $\|Tx\| \geq \alpha \|x\|$ for all $x$

Consequently, if $y=T(x)$ then

$\|T^{-1}(y)\| \leq \frac{1}{\alpha}\|T(x)\|=\alpha\|y\|$

I am wondering how this shows that the inverse must be continuous for $\inf_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\|>0$ as I clearly need to brush up on some basic Analysis skills.

Any explanation of how this shows the inverse must be continous would be greatly appreciated. I would just like a better understanding. Thanks

Comment: You showed that $T^{-1}$ is a bounded operator, which is equivalent to continuity for linear operators on normed spaces.

Comment: Ah yes! A bounded linear operator is continuous? I know every continuous function is bounded, but is the reverse true. I can see I have shown it is bounded so this is sufficient? Thanks!

Comment: Just to point out: "Then for $x\neq 0$, $\|T(x)\| = \|x\|\|T(\frac{x}{\|x\|})\| \leq \alpha \|x\|$." I'm not sure of this conclusion, due to $\alpha$ is the infimum. What you can say is $\|T(x)\|\geq \alpha \|x\|$, in this way, you can follow as you say and deduce the same inequality $\|T^{-1}(y)\| \leq \alpha\|y\|$.

Comment: This is from some exercise sheets so I am assuming it is okay?

Comment: Oh sorry it was meant to be what you said!!!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It was actually a typo and was wrong before

Comment: No problem. Do you understand why the proof works?

Comment: I think so. Because I have shown it is bounded (Dont worry I knew that bit) but every bounded function is continuous? I know that every continuous function is bounded, well just got reminded by Moya, but I am trying to search if the reverse is true as I cannot find much or remember. Would you say that would be sufficient? I haven't had to write proofs much for my last year of university so most definitely need to work on them again.. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Rudin, _Functional Analysis_, Theorem 1.32, page 23. There you can find the proof of this equivalence. Clearly, Rudin prove a general version; for Topological vector spaces. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I am actually more confused now. I have found a very old version of that book so not 100% it is the same theorem though sounds it. Is it just because it is bounded that makes it continuous?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22290/discussion-between-mrselberg-and-bernard-mathews).